# Custom delete method for

Tags: django

**Django 1.10.4**

I want to use a custom delete method for deleting bunches of my models.

**list_.models.py**

```
class MyQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):

    def delete(self):
        print("deleted")
        pdb.set_trace()
        raise SuspiciousFileOperation


class NoDeleteManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return MyQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)


class MyModel(models.Model):

    objects = NoDeleteManager()
```

In the shell:

```
>>> from list_.models import MyModel
>>> m = MyModel.objects.create()
>>> m
<MyModel: MyModel object>
>>> m.id
1
>>> ml = MyModel.objects.all()
>>> ml
<QuerySet [<MyModel: MyModel object>]>
>>> ml.delete()
(1, {'list_.MyModel': 1})
>>> ml
<QuerySet []>
```

Well, all objects from the list deleted without any sign. This means that my custom manager somehow was not applied.

Could you help me understand where my fault is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this, based on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/#calling-custom-queryset-methods-from-the-manager

```
class MyQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):

    def delete(self):
        print("deleted")
        pdb.set_trace()
        raise SuspiciousFileOperation


class NoDeleteManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return MyQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def delete(self):
        return self.get_queryset().delete()

class MyModel(models.Model):

    objects = NoDeleteManager()
```

Comment: No. Deletes as usual. I am playing with this code now. Change it in various ways. Something like this: class MyModel(models.Model): no_delete = NoDeleteManager() Not working as expected. It deletes objects without any notification.

Comment: so why do you want to override delete

Comment: For learning purposes. Somehow started working with MyQuerySet.as_manager(). But why didn't it work as you suggested is a mystery.

Comment: Yeah, it works with as_manager(). But not with the more verbose variant as I tried to organize.

Comment: when you use ` no_delete = NoDeleteManager()` and user `MyModel.no_delete.all().delete()` is it still deleting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139941/discussion-between-rrmerugu-and-michael).

Comment: @rrmerugu Just in case: are you aware about the typo `get_query_set` instead of `get_queryset`?

Comment: @alber ssh, how did i even miss that :(  thanks for pointing it out.